# Word spelling suggesting tool tip shows vertically in portrait

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air, screen-orientation

On iPhone 5 and iPhone 6+ the word spelling suggesting tool tip appears vertically for some reason (See images).

We read data from the accelerometer sensor through the ANE and then set the StageAspectRatio within AS3.

1. Run app on landscape
2. Click home button to hibernate
3. Rotate the device vertical
4. Reopen app
5. write an incorrect word
6. Notice the word spelling suggesting tool tip showing vertically in portrait mode.

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Wow, this is really weird :) I'll share my thoughts as an answer because it's easier to format

First question is why do you do that manually ? There is an autoOrients property in the app descriptor that would handle the orientation for you. Even if you don't want to use it and still want to do it manually you might try it out and see if that would fix the problem (I'd guess so).

Second question is why do you rely on the accelerometer via an ANE? There is an easy way to catch up orientation changes:

```
stage.addEventListener(StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGE, onOrientationChanged); 

private function onOrientationChanged(event:StageOrientationEvent):void
{ 
    doSomething(); 
}
```

And another note is that there are two orientation related properties - stage.deviceOrientation and stage.orientation. You might want to check these values, maybe it will give you a hint on what's going on. Normally you do change stage.setAspectRatio() but you could also try stage.setOrientation(). This will not work on all devices thought, you need to check stage.supportedOrientations first.